# throw their lot in with them

Tags: grammar

Does the phrase "throw their lot in with them" sound natural to you?  We usually use the sequence of "throw in their lot with them" that is typically idiomatic use of the idiom "throw in (one's) lot with (someone or something)". "In with" - putting the two prepositional words doesn't sound very smooth to me.

Of Dogs And Men
Chester was my window on the mysterious bond between canines and humans

By Charles Krauthammer Monday, June 16, 2003

The way I see it, dogs had this big meeting, oh, maybe 20,000 years ago. A huge meeting--an international convention with delegates from everywhere. And that's when they decided that humans were the up-and-coming species and dogs were going to **throw their lot in with them**. The decision was obviously not unanimous. The wolves and dingoes walked out in protest.

Source:   http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,1005023,00.html

Comment: No, it doesn't sound natural to me.

Comment: Seems normal and natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metaphor "throw one's lot in" is a gambling metaphor,  meaning to bet on a particular outcome, in such a way that there is no going back. Once you have thrown your lot in, you can't change your mind.

You could say, for example, "Harris threw her lot in with Biden when she agreed to become his running mate."  She is (metaphorically) betting that Biden will win.

In this fanciful narrative, the dogs are betting that humans will be the dominant species. They threw their lot in with us.